# extjs4 - filter grid drag and drop

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I've got 2 grids with drag and drop enabled.

On one of the grids I would need to check the dropped elements and filter out some of them.

I can't quite figure out how to do this. The grid dd plugin has 2 events: beforedrop and drop.

During the beforedrop event, I can check if each of the dropped records are ok, but there's no obvious way to select a subset of the records being dropped.
The only option I seem to have is to return false if I want to cancel the drop entirely - whereas I want to drop only a select subset of records.

The drop event seems too late.

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've found a workaround the issue.

The idea is to replace the *records* property of the *data* parameter in beforedrop.

(The *records* property is basically an array of Model/Records dropped on the grid)

So, with this example config for the grid:

```
viewConfig: {
    plugins: {
        dropGroup: 'items',
        ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop'
    },
    listeners: {
        beforedrop: this.onBeforeDropItem,
        scope:this
    }

}
```

The handler for beforedrop looks like this:

```
,onBeforeDropItem: function(node, data, overModel, dropPosition, dropFunction, options)
{

    var final_records = [];
    nrecords = data.records.length;
    for(var i=0;i<nrecords;i++)
    {
        var record = data.records[i];
        if (/* your condition goes here */)
        {
            final_records.push(record);
        }
    }
    data.records = final_records;
}
```

(in my case, the condition is to test if the record is already in my local grid store, but could be anything else)

Maybe I'm re-inventing the wheel though. Has anyone got a better solution?